# Is airflow uses celery beat

Tags: celery, airflow, celerybeat

Is airflow using celery beat? I know it can be easy question but I couldnt find the solution. and How can I add celery task to Airflow.

Answer (score 0):

No. Airflow has own scheduler. For more information run this in an environment where you have installed Apache Airflow: `airflow scheduler --help`

Comment: Okay but when i write airflow workerit starts celery worker. How about this?

Comment: Airflow Scheduler triggers tasks that run on Airflow Workers (Celery). Celery beat is not involved at all. You do not need Celery beat to run tasks on your Celery workers.

Comment: I am trying to understand and there is no so much comparison between airflow and celery beat. what is the difference between airflow beat and celery beat

Comment: There is no "airflow beat" - as I mentioned they have Airflow Scheduler that serves the same purpose - it triggers dags at particular time, or at specified intervals. I would argue that Celery beat is better as you can easily extend it (check red-beat or beatx projects for an example).

Comment: ok thank you very much, I am quite undestanding between airflow and celery thanks to you. There is not document about comparison between these tools in heavy job condition. Airflow or celery which one is suitable for heavy tasks?